# Getting data from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a 'orders' table in my DB (MySql) and in there I want to get 4 fields.

1. salesman
2. client
3. isert_date
4. qtd_order

But I just want the last order that every cliente have made, so i used this SQL query

```
SELECT 
    salesman, 
    client, 
    insert_date, 
    qtd_order 
FROM 
    `orders` 
WHERE 
    salesman = 'daniel.costa' 
GROUP BY 
    client 
ORDER BY 
    insert_date
```

But it gets me the first order and not the last one.

Could you help me get it.

Comment: Try adding `DESC` after `ORDER BY insert_date`

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  Your query doesn't even make sense.

Comment: What I want is the last order of each client of "daniel", thats why I used the 'GROUP BY' on the client and 'ORDER BY' in insert_date

Answer (score 1):

You need to `ORDER BY DESC` to start with the most recent ...  And if you only want 1, you can `LIMIT 1`  --  There is no need to `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT salesman, client, insert_date, qtd_order FROM 
orders WHERE salesman = 'daniel.costa' ORDER BY insert_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes it brings me all the orders of all the clients from "daniel", but I just want the last one of each client of  "daniel", thats why I used the 'GROUP BY'

Comment: So does that mean the query I supplied didn't work?  If I understand you correctly .. This query is still the most efficient way to do it.  What is does is: 1) Gets all orders from sales where salesman = daniel.  THEN it orders all those sales by date starting with the "latest" and **descending** to the oldest = `DESC`.  THEN it "cherry picks" the first result and discards the rest of them with `LIMIT 1`.